# AJAX with callback functions

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am having trouble access data within an ajax connection.  Not sure what is wrong with my code. It seems as though it never reaches the 2nd function.  Any ideas?

```
function fetchgps(callback)
{
  var url = "http://www.instamapper.com/api?action=getPositions&key=584014439054448247";

  var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  myRequest.onload = function(e) {xml_loaded(e, myRequest, callback);}
  myRequest.open("GET", url);
  myRequest.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
  myRequest.setRequestHeader("wx", "385");
 myRequest.send(null);

 return myRequest;
}

function xml_loaded(event, request, callback)
{
 if (request.responseText){
  var obj = {error:false, errorString:null}

   var data = myRequest.responseText;
   collected=data.split(",");   //parses the data delimited by comma and put data into array

obj.latitude = collected[4];
obj.longitude = collected[5];

callback(obj);
  }

  else
{
callback ({error:true, errorString:"XML request failed. no responseXML"}); //Could be any number of things..
}

}

function dealwithgps(obj)
{
lat = obj.latitude;
lon = obj.longitude;
document.write(lon);
document.write(lat);
}

fetchgps(dealwithgps);
```

Answer (score 3):

Thats [request.onreadystatechange](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#handler-xhr-onreadystatechange) instead of `request.onload`

```
function fetchgps(callback)
{
  var url = 
   "http://www.instamapper.com/api?action=getPositions&key=584014439054448247";

  var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // myRequest.onload = function(e) {xml_loaded(e, myRequest, callback);}
  myRequest.onraedystatechange = function() { //onraedystatechange instead of onload!!
    xml_loaded(myRequest, callback);
  }
  myRequest.open("GET", url);
  myRequest.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
  myRequest.setRequestHeader("wx", "385");
 myRequest.send(null);

 return myRequest;
}

function xml_loaded(request, callback) {
   if(request.readyState === 4) {
       //... only then do your processing
   }
}
```

Comment: Tried that already...I get an error from the browser...."The data necessary to complete that operation is not yet available"

Comment: You will have to chech for myRequest.readystate and only do processing when the ready state is 4. Check my answer.

Comment: That at least got me further that I was before. I added this if ((request.readyState == 4) && (request.status == 200).  However I'm not reaching these states and its throwing an error to the callback. Not sure why, if I do it a different way its fine.

Comment: Appears to be a scope issue...i tested by adding the following line below the readyState statement.  /alert(request.responseText);
I get back the alert message.   Any ideas?

Comment: Figured it out... My "Else" statement in the xml_loaded function was tripping even though the matching if stated if ((request.readyState == 4) && (request.status == 200). Not sure why, but it was returning an error. I just negated the if statement in the else and it worked fine. Thanks for the help

Comment: Why not use jQuery? Also, use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to catch stuff like that.